# Fee for product with returnable container

Tags: custom-options, ce-1.9.1.0

I'm looking for free solution how to add fee to several products. Those products include returnable container and I don't want to see it in price but it has to be in total as 'returnable containers' - 2 USD for example.

I tried to do it by Product > Custom Options > Radio buttons but customer would have to check the button. I need to have it as non-optional.

Thank you.

Comment: You can make that option as required in admin panel itself

Comment: I know but it doesn't make it checked. Is there option to do so?

Comment: You need a default value to select in radio button right?